# Newline in label for Django form field

Tags: django, forms, field

Is there a way to put a newline in the label of a form field in Django? Putting a `\n` just results in a newline in the HTML, and trying `<br>` just displays the characters as they are.  Is there an equivalent `|safe` operation that I can specify on the field?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `mark_safe` so that the `<br />` tag is not escaped.

It's equivalent to using `safe` in the template, so be careful if you're handling user input. If it's a hardcoded string, then it's safe to use.

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField(label=mark_safe('my label<br />next line'))
```

Comment: I think an alternative is to use {{my_field.label|linebreaks}} in the template

Comment: @Anupam that's a good suggestion, you should add it as a separate answer. Another option is `linebreaksbr`.

Comment: @Alasdair added it as answer

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this directly in the template as follows:

```
 {{my_field.label|linebreaks}}
```

`\n` will convert to `<br/>` that way

As per the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks),

> a single
>   newline becomes an HTML line break (`<br />`) and a new line followed by
>   a blank line becomes a paragraph break (`</p>`).