# Force newline in django form validation error string

Tags: python, css, django, forms, validation

How do I force a Django form to display a newline at a specific point in the validation error string?

I've tried using `\n\n` as well as a `<br>` in the validate functions in `forms.py` and neither works.  HTML doesn't care about the newlines and `<br>` gets escaped instead of rendered as a newline.

---

The error strings are something similar to the following:

`raise ValidationError(f"'{value}' matched {match_count} objects.\n\n<br>Please be more specific.`

I want to force the newline between sentences.  If there is some HTML+CSS trick to do so using the period as the delimiter, I am open to that.

Comment: You might want to check the answer to this question. Helped me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653471/newline-in-label-for-django-form-field